# DirectQuery with parameters PowerBI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I try to create report and have some table with some values my purpose is when clicking on some row of table it should drill through to other page with line chart, my question is I have column ***EventTime*** and when I click on some row it should drill through on line chart where as X axis will be time and that time should have range +-5 minutes of EventTime column how can I make this? Is this possible to create DirectQuery SQL statement with parameters and if possible how can I change this parameters depends on filtered row column ***EventTime*** or there are some other possibilites?
Kindly thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I don't think they have exact solution for this, I also tried to do similar thing, Unfortunately couldn't found useful resource.

Try some custom visualizations, in import more visualizations, Obviously most of effective ones are paid versions, But you can do some stuff from free versions.